# Google Play Subscription not charging bill from real clients in my android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I am implementing **Google Play Billing** in my **android app**. I am selling **Google Play Subscriptions**.

- When I use the **test card**, google is successfully charging the subscription fee.
- The **problem** is, when a **real user** try to purchase a subscription plan, he is successfully subscribed to the plan but google is charging **0$**.
- I have rechecked my code several times

**Please help me regarding this issue.**

Screenshot of Google Play console.

[image: Google Play console Payments Record]

Here is my code for **BillingClient**:

```
public class BillingHandler implements ASubscriptionClickListener,
        PurchasesUpdatedListener,
        AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
    {

private static String TAG = BillingHandler.class.getSimpleName();
private Activity activity;
private List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList;
private BillingClient billingClient;
private RecyclerView rvSKUs;

public BillingHandler(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.rvSKUs = recyclerView;
    initBillingClient();
}

private void initBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    Log.e(TAG, "billing client built.");
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                Log.e(TAG, "billing client setup successful.");
                queryAvailablePlans();
            }else {
                Log.e(TAG, "billing client setup failed.");
                handleAllBillingErrors(billingResult);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() { }
    });
}

private void handleAllBillingErrors(BillingResult billingResult){
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        showAFailureMsg("User cancelled the purchase after showing plans to the user", false);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        showAFailureMsg("Feature not supported on this phone.", true);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.DEVELOPER_ERROR) {
        showAFailureMsg("DEVELOPER_ERROR", false);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE) {
        showAFailureMsg("BILLING_UNAVAILABLE", false);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        showAFailureMsg("ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED", false);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED) {
        showAFailureMsg("ITEM_NOT_OWNED", false);
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE) {
        showAFailureMsg("ITEM_UNAVAILABLE", false);
    }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        showAFailureMsg("SERVICE_DISCONNECTED", false);
    }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
        showAFailureMsg("SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", false);
    }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_TIMEOUT) {
        showAFailureMsg("SERVICE_TIMEOUT", false);
    } else {
        showAFailureMsg("Something went wrong while setting up purchase after showing plans to the user", false);
    }
}

/**
 * get all plans from play console!
 */
private void queryAvailablePlans() {
    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
            skuList.add("1_months_plan");
            skuList.add("3_months_plan");
            skuList.add("6_months_plan");
            skuList.add("12_months_plan");
  
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            (billingResult, skuDetailsList) -> {
                //loaded all available the subscription plans.
                // Process the result.
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                    String msg = "SKU details response received: OK (Number of Plans:" + skuDetailsList.size() + ")";
                    Log.e(TAG, msg);
                    this.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList;

                    //Show all plans
                    if (rvSKUs != null) {
                        rvSKUs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
                        rvSKUs.setAdapter(new RVAdapt_SKUs(this.skuDetailsList, activity, this));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "SKU details response received: null");
                }
            });
}

/**
 * On update of a purchase plan
 * @param purchase details of subscription/ purchase of user
 */
private void handlePurchase(BillingClient client, Purchase purchase) {
    Log.e(TAG, "handling a pending purchase");
    if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Successfully purchased a plan(" + purchase.getSku() + "). \t Order ID: "
                + purchase.getOrderId() + ". Token: " + purchase.getPurchaseToken());

        // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "not acknowledged yet!!");
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();
            purchaseToAcknowledge = purchase;
            client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, this);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Already Acknowledged");
        }
    } else if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING
            || purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE) {
        MyShrdPref.instantiate(activity).writePlanType(MyGlobalAppData.PLANS_TYPES.FREE);
        MyFirebaseServices.saveOrRemovePlan(activity, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "A pending payment found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "A pending payment found!");
    }
}

private void showAFailureMsg(String msg, boolean exit){
    Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(TAG, msg);
    if (exit)activity.finish();
}

    /**
     * Listener for SKUs RecyclerView to get the the clicked sku
     * @param skuDetails clicked sku details
     */
@Override
public void onClick(SkuDetails skuDetails) {
    //Callback which returns the selected sku by the user
    if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS)
            .getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        //Show purchase process/ flow
        BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                .build();
        BillingResult responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);
        if (responseCode.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Log.e("BillingHandler", "billing flow completed successfully!");
        }
        handleAllBillingErrors(responseCode);
    }
}


private Purchase purchaseToAcknowledge;
@Override
public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
    if (purchaseToAcknowledge==null) return;

    if (billingResult.getResponseCode()==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "purchaseToAcknowledge: " + purchaseToAcknowledge.getPackageName()
                + "\n Purchase Acknowledgment Time: "
                + purchaseToAcknowledge.getPurchaseTime()
        );

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        String message = "Congrats! You have successfully subscribed for premium features.\n\n";
        for (SkuDetails d : skuDetailsList) {
            if (d.getSku().equals(purchaseToAcknowledge.getSku())) {
                MyFirebaseServices.saveOrRemovePlan(activity, d, null);
                message += "Plan: " + d.getTitle() + "\n\n";
                message += "" + d.getDescription() + "\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        message += "OrderID: " + purchaseToAcknowledge.getOrderId();

        builder.setTitle("Subscription successful")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Okay", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                })
                .show();
    }else handleAllBillingErrors(billingResult);
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchaseList) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
            && purchaseList != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchaseList) {
            handlePurchase(billingClient, purchase);
        }
    } else{
        handleAllBillingErrors(billingResult);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is Google charging $0 or is it charging the amount you want but customers ask for refund and consequently registered but not charged?

Comment: @AliHas google is charging 0$ and showing successful subscription in both response as well as on play console.

Comment: @AliHas google is charging 0$ fee even on acknowledgement of the purchase.